# NoMethodError - Undefined method `set'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[No method error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08AHR.png)

Hi I am running into this NoMethodError, when i try to show the first user in my database. My user controller is below:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @users.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully 
updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully 
destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white 
list through.
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
end
end
```

and my views/users/show basically just prints the users name and email

```
<%= @user.name %><% @user.email %>
```

Comment: just there is typo in `before_action`

Answer (score 1):

Fix this

```
before_action :set_
```

to

```
before_action :set_user
```

Answer (score 0):

> NoMethodError - Undefined method `set_' for

The error is from

```
before_action :set_, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Probably you meant `set_user`

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line with

```
before_action :set_, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

this

```
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are two errors in the code you have pasted here.

```
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

and also in the 'update' method, the object is '@user' and not '@users'. Please change

```
@users.update(user_params)
```

to

```
@user.update(user_params)
```